# How do I include line breaks when using an XElement?

Tags: xml, newline, xelement

I have a web service that accepts XML data. Included in the data is an <address> tag  whose data could contain a new line.

How do I include the new line? I tried using the HTML line break tag <br />, but this was removed when accessing the XElement's Value property, leaving me with the address on a single line. I also tried using real lines breaks, but that caused problems parsing the XML.

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: "*I also tried using real lines breaks, but that caused problems parsing the XML*". What kind of problem, any error message? And how did you try exactly? real line breaks should be fine

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear! It was quoted from another developer who is using the web service, and who was having problems including real line breaks in his XML, as he's using Delphi, and doesn't know how to handle line breaks in strings properly (or maybe Delphi doesn't support this, don't know). He switched to using <br /> instead, as that is a standard way to indicate a line break. Problem is that when accessing the XElement's Value property, the <br /> is stripped, and not turned into a line break. I'd like to know how I can get the value with line breaks. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `\n` while adding content

```
XElement XEleEmp = new XElement("Employee");
XElement XEleAdd = new XElement("Address", "Plot No. 123 \nXYZ Villa \nRoad No. 321\n");
XEleEmp.Add(XEleAdd);
```

XML:

```
<Employee>
  <Address>Plot No. 123
XYZ Villa
Road No. 321
</Address>
</Employee>
```

Comment: Thanks, I discovered this after posting, but as no-one answered, i forgot about the question, and didn't come back to add an answer. You get the points for spotting it!